# Heisig and New JLPT (Post 2009)

Tags: discussion, kanji

I'm trying to find a table with both the Heisig (RTK) Kanji characters that lists both Kanji character numbers as well as current JLPT numbers (N5 to N1).

So far, I've found [one here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqYInAMvWw-2ckJSVktXSGtMSVgwbGdYNHZudDB2TEE&hl=en#gid=0) but it only has the old JLPT relationship.

Does such a list exist?

Comment: Unless you are going for N3 I wouldn't would treat all the levels the same as the old old information suggests.

Comment: There is no official kanji list for the new JLPT. So anything you could find will be approximated guesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read that there [will be no official kanji lists published because they're discouraging studying based on lists](http://www.jlpt.jp/e/faq/index.html#anchor24). The lists that you found are probably based on observation of many years of JLPT to determine which level requires which kanji. Since the the new N-levels are a relatively new thing, I think it would take a couple more years to observe the new levels and create new comprehensive lists.

In short, I think such a list does not exist (yet).

Comment: +1 for not learning by a list for the JLPT.

Comment: @summea. Lists are useful up to N4 I think. I had significant progress in my vocabulary based on mass memorising 60~80 words a day up to the 2000-word vocabulary mark. Beyond that it's nigh impossible to improve based on lists because words get semantically heavy and have nuances and meanings that lists cannot express. Exposure to full sentences in real contexts become much more useful for learning.

Comment: I've used lists, as well.  It's just not a natural way to learn a language, however, when remembering how language is (usually) naturally acquired.  I like the efficiency of lists... but like you mention about nuances (and multiple word meanings and uses,) lists can only go so far.  My previous comment is mostly a +1 to anyone who decides to learn Japanese in a more natural way... at least, without resorting to lists.

Comment: The lists cannot be based on many years of JLPT, since there has only been a couple exams total since the new system is in place (and less for N3, which is only once a year). Most of these lists seem to be built using other criteria, such as frequency or grade school level.

Comment: @summea What is the natural way you're referring to?

Comment: @Alenanno Something like childhood learning.

Comment: @summea Ok, but that is not possible when you're not a child. No method is natural unless you grow up in a certain place. I prefer learning through exercises for example, but lists are useful as they can help you to understand what material you can focus on.

Comment: @Alenanno it's difficult... but it's not impossible.  I did say "something like"... which is different than saying "childhood learning" by itself.  Lists are fairly abstract ways of learning information.  Children tend to learn things physically (or in an applied way.)  That is what I am aiming at, here.